# Import modules with the same name in different path in different thread of Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, import, python-import

Here i have two python packages with the exactly same hierarchy and folder names (Actually they are just the same packages of different version)

```
version1\
     lib\ 
         __init__.py
         overall.py
         modules\
                module.py

version2\
     lib\
         __init__.py
         overall.py
         modules\
                module.py
```

What i want is to create a function, and call this function with an argument to specify the version and import corresponding lib, like this

```
def do_something(version):
  if version == 1:
    sys.path.append('./version1')
  elif version == 2:
    sys.path.append('./version2')

  import lib
  #do the reset things with the lib
```

But this function doesn't work in multiple threads, because `sys.path` is shared by all threads in one process.If after `sys.path.append` and before      `import lib`, another thread cut in, current thread will finally import a wrong lib.

I've come up with 2 solutions, but neither of them works.

**Solution 1:**

Add a thread lock when accessing `sys.path`, and call `sys.path.remove` after `import lib`. However this doesn't work because functions or methods may **dynamically** import other modules in the same packages. So if you call functions of the lib after `sys.path.remove`, it will raise an error `can not find module`.

Of course you could say lock the entire `do_something` function and only release the lock just before function return. Yes, it works, but my program will become a single thread program.Actually it is `do_something` which is my thread function.

**Solution 2:**

Add empty **init**.py in `version1` and `version2`, so my folders will become like this

```
version1\
     __init__.py
     lib\ 
         __init__.py
         overall.py
         modules\
                module.py

version2\
     __init__.py
     lib\
         __init__.py
         overall.py
         modules\
                module.py
```

And codes like this:

```
def do_something(version):
  if version == 1:
    import version1.lib
  elif version == 2:
    import version2.lib
    sys.path.append('./version2')

  #do the reset things with the lib
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work either. Because in `lib\overall.py`, it import module like this `import lib.modules.module`. and it fails and can't find module.

So, how can i do it in multithreads? Is there anyway to maintain a **private  sys.path for threads** to import modules?

Comment: Could you put a lock around `sys.path.append(); import lib as x; sys.path.reset()`?

Comment: @TomDalton That's the same as solution 1.  It still doesn't work

Comment: Sorry, it's early. Even uglier, but could you add something that uses `importlib` to recursively import everything inside lib inside the lock?

Comment: Another possible solution would be to use `multiprocessing` instead of `threading`, which would allow you better control over the system path of each process.

Comment: @TomDalton even i imported all libs (sys.modules is also shared by threads). How does subsequent import know which version to import?

Comment: I believe python caches the modules internally, so once a module is imported, a subsequent import won't go to disk but will retrieve it from the cache.

Comment: Yeah, i know it. But , the cache (which is sys.modules) is also shared by threads, even subsequent import only retrieve them from cache, how does python know which one(both of two versions will be in cache if in multiple threads)

Comment: I think the easiest solution might be to swap to multiprocessing. Who knows what global memory each version of the lib might create anyway, so even if you can make the imports work the 2 versions might not work properly in parallel anyway.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73333/discussion-between-demonguy-and-tom-dalton).

Comment: This is an abuse of the module system. Why do you want this?

Comment: @PatrickCollins I already said, i need different version

Comment: Why do you have two versions of the same library floating around? Why is it better to do this than to just, say, merge the two libraries together?

Comment: because new version isn't backward compatible

Comment: @demonguy i am also stuck in a similar problem, have you found any solution to it.